# proper conversion for non-standard bit length floating points

Tags: floating-point, floating-point-conversion

I am working on a project that requires floating point conversions for non-standard bit lengths of under 32-bits. Is there a IEEE standard for the components (`exponent`, `mantissa`) lengths? For example, for an 8-bit the two most chosen options are `0 000 0000` or `0 0000 000` is one of these more correct or does it depend on the protocol one is trying to read? What about an 11-bit floating point?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a standard for non-standard formats?

Comment: yes it reads that way...A standard scale ie. how we scale the length of our exponent down or up from 8bits.

Comment: Table 3.5 of the IEEE-754 (2008) standard gives some general formulas, but only for floating-point data types comprising a multiple of 32 bits. In practical terms, for a narrow custom format, the requirements of the use case(s) on dynamic range probably dictate how many bits must be dedicated to the exponent, leaving the rest for the mantissa.One might even be able to save the sign bit if the occurrence of negative data can be excluded with certainty. For what it is worth, crude extrapolation of the existing IEEE-754 binary types to an 8-bit type would suggest four mantissa bits.